# Generating a Monte Carlo estimate of a function of a normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, monte-carlo, simulation

Suppose I have a function g(Z), where Z has a uniform normal distribution. If I wanted to estimate its expected value, via Monte Carlo simulation, would it be correct to generate a sample of Z, then plug that into g(Z)*f(Z), where f is the PDF of Z, and then take the mean? Thanks!

Comment: thanks! when might we get a biased estimation?

Comment: The easiest way is, draw Z for n times, for each drawn Z calculate  g(Z), sum each calculated g(Z) then divide by n, with n large it converges to the expected value of g(Z)